# matrix diagonalization with properties on its powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let A be a complex matrix of dimension $n$. Suppose that exists a natural number $r$ such that $A^r=c I_n$ , where $I_n$ is the identity matrix and $c$ is a complex number. For what values of $c$, is $A$ diagonalizable? I could only prove that $c$ must be different from zero.

Sorry if I didn't write everything in the correct way, but i'm new on this site. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If $c \ne 0$, $A^r = c B^r$ where $B = c^{-1/r} A$, and $B$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is.  So the value of $c$ doesn't make a difference, as long as it's not $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c\neq 0$ you have $P=X^r-c$ which is a cancelling split (in $\mathbb C$) polynom with simple roots for $A$, hence $A$ is diagonalizable.